# Same map but appears very differently in my application

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers Javascript API to display the US topological map ([https://b.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://b.tile.opentopomap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)). In my app Mount Rainier appears as

[image]

However If I go to the website of the same map provider (https://opentopomap.org/#map=12/46.8611/-121.7474). The map appears totally different but its the same US Topo map

Why are the 2 images so different when supposedly I am using the same map (same url?)

[image]

Edit: if you are wondering what code I wrote to arrive at image 1 then please find it below

```
var feature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Point(Proj.fromLonLat([
    -121.08700000094,
    47.9176999997368
  ]))
  });
  var style = new Style.Style({
    image: new Style.Icon({
    color: "#BADA55",
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
    src: "images/hiking.png",
    scale: 0.2})
  });
  feature.setStyle(style);
  new VectorJs({
    features: [feature]
  });
  var osm = new OSM({
    url: "https://b.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  });
  var tileLayer = new Tile({
    title: "OSM",
    type: "base",
    visible: true,
    source: osm
   });
   new $$Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [tileLayer],
    view: new View({
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      center: [-121.02524898891282,47.440536890633204],
      zoom: 8.7
    })
  });
}), []);
return JsxRuntime.jsx("div", {
  className: "map",
  id: "map"
});
```

Comment: Using your code I get the right image with OL 7.1.0, although it doesn't make much sense using OSM source if you change url, natural choice would be XYZ source. What you are getting is OSM map, so it looks like browser cache problem because you might have used pure OSM layer initially.

Comment: XYZ source is not working for me. If I try to do "new XYX()" instead of new "new OSM()" I get a blank screen with no errors.

Comment: Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/bgLj1d37/